# How can I know how many column of a table have at least a value > or < of a number?

Tags: r

```
library(tidyverse)
gbm_vec <- function(nsim = 1000, t = 5, mu = 0.1, sigma =.3, S0 = 3400, dt = 1/252) {
  epsilon <- matrix(rnorm(t*nsim, sd = .3, mean = .0004), ncol = nsim, nrow = t) 
                    gbm <- exp((mu - sigma * sigma / 2) * dt + sigma * epsilon * sqrt(dt)) 
                    gbm <- apply(rbind(rep(S0, nsim), gbm), 2, cumprod)
                    return(gbm)
}
nsim <- 1000
t <- 5
mu <- 0.1
sigma <- .3
S0 <- 3477.13
gbm <- gbm_vec(nsim, t, mu, sigma, S0) #function to have the table I'm talking about
View(gbm)
```

Run the code to see the table.
How can I know how many of the 1000 columns have at least a value bigger than, lets say, 3500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `colSums` :

```
val <- 3500
sum(colSums(gbm > val) > 0)
```

`colSums(gbm > val)` counts total number of values in each column which is greater than `val`. We then count how many columns have at least 1 value greater than `val` with `sum`.

Comment: After that, how can I remove all these columns from the table gbm and just have a table without them but with all the other columns? By the way, your answear worked perfectly.

Comment: You mean `gbm[gbm > val] <- NA` like this?

Comment: I mean, assuming I have 100 columns and 30 (for example) have at least a value > 3500, How can I remove these 30 columns from the table of 100 and have just the other 70 columns? Or at least remove every numeric value from the 30 columns and keeping them in the table

Comment: ohh...that would be `result <- gbm[, colSums(gbm > val) == 0]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse approach, illustrated using `mtcars` and checking for any value > 1 in all numeric columns:

```
mtcars %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, ~any(. > 1)) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  count(value)

#   value n
# 1 FALSE 2
# 2  TRUE 9
```

The result tells you how many of the numeric columns had at least one value > 1 and how many didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64337062/12158757) is super elegant. Here is another option using `crossprod`

```
sum(crossprod(rep(1,nrow(gbm)),gbm)>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums`

```
val <- 3500
sum(rowSums(t(gbm > val)) > 0)
```

---

Or with `apply`

```
sum(apply(gbm, 2, function(x) sum(x > val)))
```